# Cant Import ,While Importing products in magento getting this Error

Tags: php, magento

I have imported around 60 thousand of products in magento 1.7.0. But Now whenever I'm trying to import, After clicking on **check data** button  file get uploaded 100% and then browser goes down by showing waiting for www.mydomain.com without responding anything without showing **Import** button. I seen my log file n here is the error I got:

```
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M140518 22:43:24 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140518 22:43:39 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140518 22:43:39  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140518 22:43:39  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140518 22:43:39  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 13 2053745225
140518 22:43:39 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140518 22:43:39 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.69'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

I have to import more products so please someone help me to resolve !

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an error. I think you need to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If those are simple products create batches to import products with less load on server and faster response time.

Comment: yes those all are simple products. will u please explain in details about batches, how can i use it.